# How to start using onelogin services as a developer?

Tags: onelogin

I have to develop an web application in ASP.NET MVC. I have to integrate the onelogin service in my app. For example, if user is login in another app with the help of onelogin.com, and user hits my app then user get login into my app also without demanding credentials.
I want to know that from where I should start do this task? Please provide steps to perform this.

Answer (score 0):

In a nutshell, SAML is the way to go.

Check out our opensource toolkits here: https://developers.onelogin.com/saml/c-and-aspnet